# how to have default value for a text field only for new form in rails? iam using :value => "0".but in edit form also iam getting '0' value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, default, textfield

How to have default value for a text field only for new form in rails? I am using `:value => "0"` in form partial. But the problem is though I have a value in database, I am getting 0 in edit form. actually in new form for a text field I am assigning 0 by default, when the user not select any value. but when user changes that value and saves the form,then also while displaying edit form I am getting "0" value. how to avoid display of "0" when there is a value in database in edit form? this is the syntax I am using.

```
   <%= f.text_field :duration , :size=>"4", :value => "0" %>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
<%= f.text_field :duration , :size=>"4", :value => (f.object.duration || 0) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= f.text_field :duration , :size=>"4", :value => (f.object.duration || 0 ) %>
```

It will display if duration is present else it will display 0.

You can also do like this:

```
 <%= f.text_field :duration , :size=>"4", :value => (0 unless f.object.new_record?) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

`FormBuilder` tries to pull values in from the given object. It may not not even be an ActiveRecord model, so it's totally possible to provide default values without having them in the database. So how do you do that?

#### Sure you could fill in the value in your input field:

But the resulting markup is a bit ugly. Plus, it's not the views' job to define your data.

#### Read this, but don't do this:

A sorta dumb (but quick and working way) would be assigning the default values in the controller:

```
def new
  @something = Something.new # Even unpersisted objects store some data
  @something.value = 'hi'    # No DB queries, but the value will get to the form
end
```

The given value will end up in the form even though it's not in the database. And this is not really controllers' job either.

That only leaves models.

#### Instead, do this:

The fun part is we can get default values into the database. Have them right in your schema. ActiveRecord is smart enough to notice that and fill in the default fields of `Something.new` with values given in migrations.

If you're creating a table, your migration would look like this:

```
class CreateSomethings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :somethings do |t|
      t.string :key
      t.string :value, default: 'hi'

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

But you can add that even to existing tables using `change_column`.